# I am trying to Mock an autowired map of instances in spring but I get null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito

In one of my controller

```
@Autowired
    private Map<String, ABC> abcMap;
```

now I want mock it in one of the unit test but I always get null pointer exception.
This map contains implementations of ABC abstract class.

Can anyone suggest a possible solution?

Comment: I don't see how a map would be a candidate for dependency injection...

Comment: add your test pls to question

Comment: Use constructor injection.

Comment: Please add some more code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what Unit test Framework you are using but there are ways of making it inject the mock details. You'll have to give us more information before before we can answer.

Personally I don't much like Autowired private fields, so at the risk of answering a different question can I suggest you *consider* using an Autowired constructor instead. From Springs POV it won't make a difference, your object will be create and all the appropriate data wired in. (OK, there is a slight change in the order things are done, but generally you won't notice). You will have to write a constructor to copy the constructor parameters to private fields, but:

1. Those fields could be made final, which could make your class safer
2. Your Unit tests wont need any 'magic' to initialise the Autowired fields - just pass parameters
3. If you refactor you class to remove add/remove/modify an Autowired field then you have to remember to change your test code. With an Autowired constructor you test code has to be changed or it won't compile, and your IDE might even help you do it.

---

**Update**
The Autowired constructor alternative looks something like:

```
@Controller
class MyClass {
   private final Class1 bean1;
   private final Object value2;

  @Autowired
  MyClass(Class1 bean1, Class2 bean2) {
    this.bean1 = bean1;
    this.value2 = bean2.getValue();
  }
}
```

Keys points are:

1. The class has just one constructor and it requires parameters.
2. The fields are not annotated `@Autowired`, because Spring is not assigning values to them; the constructor does that.
3. The constructor IS annotated as `@Autowired` to tell Spring to pass the beans as parameters
4. The first parameter is stored in a final variable - you code can't accidentally over write it, so your code is safer
5. In my example the second parameter is only used in the constructor, so we don't have to store it as a field in your controller. I often to this if the Bean is an object that passes configuration around.
6. A No-argument constructor is not required
7. At test time your code will have to pass parameters to the class.

Your test code will look something like:

```
class MyClassTest {
  private Class1 bean1;
  private Class2 bean2;
  private MyClass objectUnderTest;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    bean1 = mock(Class1.class);
    bean2 = mock(Class2.class);
    // Train mocks here

    objectUnderTest = new MyClass(bean1, bean2)
  }

  @Test
  public void myTest() {
     // Do something with objectUnderTest 
  }
}
```

Key points are:

1. There are no @MockBean annotations
2. The Unit test is only using the API that your Controller bean defines; No black magic is required
3. It's not possible to create a MyClass with out providing the required data. This is enforced by the compiler

Comment: I tried using autowired constructor and like other fields, in the test class I tried to ``@MockBean private Map<String, ConfigurationDomain> configurationDomainMap`` I still get null pointer exception. Can u specify what other details u need?

Comment: I've update my answer with code samples; but the short answer is that you don't need `@MockBean` annotations if you use the Autowired constructor. BTW we still don't know what framework you are using

Comment: This looks fine and this use case work for me too. I am facing issue particularly ith map usecase that I have mentioned in the question

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know what you mean by _"facing issue particularly ith map usecase"_, your original question doesn't detail any particular use cases. I suggest you add the "ith map" code to the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try it.

The sample of code:

```
public interface Animal {
}

@Service
public class Cat implements Animal{
}

@Service
public class Dog implements Animal{
}

@Service
public class Clinic {
    @Autowired
    private final Map<String, Animal> animalMap = new HashMap<>(2);
}
```

Sample of test

```
@Configuration
public class TestEnvConfig {

    @Bean
    public Clinic create(){
        return new Clinic();
    }

    @MockBean // you can do it without mock or use @ComponentScan
    Dog dog;

    @MockBean
    Cat cat;
}

@SpringBootTest(classes = TestEnvConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ClinicTest {

    @Autowired
    private Clinic clinic;
}
```